# How do I best avoid possible mutluple enumerations, but also stay async at the same time?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, .net-core

Consider the following method:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<TORTDTransmissionOwner>> ReturnActiveTransmissionOwnersForUser(User inputUser)
{
    _logger.LogDebug("ReturnActiveTransmissionOwnersForUser executing with user: {0}", inputUser.Email);
    IEnumerable<TORTDTransmissionOwner> transmissionOwners;
    if (inputUser.IsAdmin || inputUser.IsApprover)
    {
        transmissionOwners = await _toStakeholderUploadDataService.GetTORTDTransmissionOwners();
        _logger.LogDebug("User isAdmin or isApprover, count of TOs: {0}", transmissionOwners.Count());
    }
    else
    {
        transmissionOwners = inputUser.TransmissionOwners.Where(to => to.IsImplemented)
            .OrderBy(to => to.TORTDTransmissionOwner.Dbaname).Select(to => to.TORTDTransmissionOwner);
        _logger.LogDebug("User is standard, count of TOs: {0}", transmissionOwners.Count());
    }
    return transmissionOwners;
}
```

Currently, ReSharper is giving me a warning that I will be causing multiple enumerations of the results from what is a database call.

But, if I change the database call to be like:

```
public Task<IEnumerable<TORTDTransmissionOwner>> ReturnActiveTransmissionOwnersForUser(User inputUser)
{
    _logger.LogDebug("ReturnActiveTransmissionOwnersForUser executing with user: {0}", inputUser.Email);
    IEnumerable<TORTDTransmissionOwner> transmissionOwners;
    if (inputUser.IsAdmin || inputUser.IsApprover)
    {
        transmissionOwners = _toStakeholderUploadDataService.GetTORTDTransmissionOwners().Result.ToList();
        _logger.LogDebug("User isAdmin or isApprover, count of TOs: {0}", transmissionOwners.Count());
    }
    else
    {
        transmissionOwners = inputUser.TransmissionOwners.Where(to => to.IsImplemented)
            .OrderBy(to => to.TORTDTransmissionOwner.Dbaname).Select(to => to.TORTDTransmissionOwner).ToList();
        _logger.LogDebug("User is standard, count of TOs: {0}", transmissionOwners.Count());
    }
    return transmissionOwners;
}
```

I've lost the need for Async and forced every database call to be syncronous. When I am not using debug logging, I would rather have async, right?

So my question is, how do I choose the right approach here? Or is there a way to write this method better so that I can have both async and my debug statements if and when I need?

Comment: In general @Xiaoy312's answer is right, but it depends on what you have inside `GetTORTDTransmissionOwners()`, what exactly does it return - is it materialized inside or not? And don't forget `ConfigureAwait(false)`.

Comment: Can you eloborate on ConfigureAwait or suggest some other answers?

Comment: Use `ToListAsync()` to keep asynchronous method.

Comment: @ZorgoZ, you don't need `ConfigureAwait` for dotnet core applications. But it would be good to have if you plan to use libraries with other .NET frameworks.

Answer (score 1):

You can also materialize after the async call returns:

```
transmissionOwners = 
    (await _toStakeholderUploadDataService.GetTORTDTransmissionOwners()).ToList();
```